# Formatting Excel cell with Microsoft Interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, formatting

I generate some Excel file with Microsoft Interop, no problem, I can create files, sheet, file, password protect. But I'd like :

- for a specific range allow only numbers
- for an another specific range allow only numbers but only 0 or 1

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took a while but I think I got it. I am assuming you're using Excel 2007. I am also assuming you have a reference to a range already. Here is a quick example.

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = this.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A5") as Excel.Range;

 //delete previous validation rules 
 range.Validation.Delete();
 range.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateWholeNumber,
                                 Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
                                 Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                                 0, 1);
```

This will add a validation of number between **0** and **1** for a specific range in this case between **A1** and **A5**.

You can also play with the **Validation** object further to create custom Error Messages etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this. But I use interop for Office 2002, it's the "standard" for my customer

Comment: @Kris, this should work either way. Let me know if it doesn't and i'll see if i can get 2002 to work.

Comment: I tried it with Visual Studio 2005 and Excel 2003, it works.  One thing I can't get is how to NOT pass the optional parameters.  According to the docs you use Type.Missing but this while this compiles it results in "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate an entry into the Cell, look at the [Validation.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.validation.add%28office.11%29.aspx) method.

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.validation%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Your second one is something like:

```
aRange.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateWholeNumber, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post a bit of code that may help, including the MS namespaces needed.

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

/// <summary>
/// setup this cell to validate (and report error) as decimal value input
/// </summary>
void SetupCellValidation_decimal(Excel.Range cell)
{
  try
  {
    // Delete any previous validation
    cell.Validation.Delete();
    // Add validation that allows any decimal value
    cell.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateDecimal, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
      Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue);

    cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true; // allow blank entries
    cell.Validation.ErrorTitle = "Invalid Entry";
    cell.Validation.ErrorMessage = "You must enter a valid number";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("validate error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
void exampleCellValidator(Excel.Range cell)
{
  try
  {
    //Delete any previous validation
    cell.Validation.Delete();

    // for integers:
    cell.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateWholeNumber, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
      Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 0, 120);

    // for decimal:
    cell.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateDecimal, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
      Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue);

    cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
    // error messaging
    cell.Validation.ErrorMessage = "Entry is not a valid number";
    cell.Validation.ErrorTitle = "Error - invalid entry";

    // use these if you want to display a message each time user activates this cell
    cell.Validation.InputTitle = "Entry Rule"; // a message box title
    cell.Validation.InputMessage = "You must enter a valid number"; // message to instruct user what to do
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("validate error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```